# Http Post With Body

Tags: java, android

i have sent method in objective-c of sending http post and in the body i put a string:

```
NSString *requestBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mystring"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

now in Android i want to do the same thing and i am looking for a way to set the body of http post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use this snippet -

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn;
URL mUrl = new URL(url);
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
...
//query is your body
urlConn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/" + "POST");
if (query != null) {
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(query.length()));
urlConn.getOutputStream().write(query.getBytes("UTF8"));
}
```

Comment: and how i connect the urlconnection to the http post?

Comment: I think need add: `urlConn.setDoOutput(true);`

Comment: Why are you using `application/POST` and not `application/JSON`?

Answer (score 14):

You can use HttpClient and HttpPost to build and send the request.

```
HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("www.example.com");

List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramName", "paramValue"));

request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs ));
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: client.setEntity should be request.setEntity

Comment: Upvoted since this helped me a lot. You may want to update DefaultHttpClient now that it is deprecated to HttpClientBuilder.create.build()

Answer (score 12):

You can use HttpClient and HttpPost to send a json string as body:

```
public void post(String completeUrl, String body) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(completeUrl);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    try {
        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(body);
        httpPost.getRequestLine();
        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

        httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Json body example:

```
{
  "param1": "value 1",
  "param2": 123,
  "testStudentArray": [
    {
      "name": "Test Name 1",
      "gpa": 3.5
    },
    {
      "name": "Test Name 2",
      "gpa": 3.8
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try something like this using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and [HttpPost](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html):

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mystring", "value_of_my_string"));
// etc...

// Post data to the server
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://...");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

then add elements for each pair

```
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yourReqVar", Value);
 nameValuePairs.add( ..... );
```

Then use the HttpPost:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

and use the `HttpClient` and `Response` to get the response from the server