# HttpPost Posting Complex JSONObject in the Body of the Request

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I was wondering, using HttpClient and HttpPOST is there a way to post a complex JSON object as the body of the request? I did see an example of posting a simple key/value pair in the body (as shown below from this link: [Http Post With Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777929/http-post-with-body)):

```
HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("www.example.com");

List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramName", "paramValue"));

request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs ));
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(request);
```

However, I would need to post something like the following:

```
{
"value": 
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "type": "weird",
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to accomplish this?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Doing the following:

```
HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("www.example.com");
String json = "{\"value\": {\"id\": \"12345\",\"type\": \"weird\"}}";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
request.setEntity(entity);
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(request);
```

results in an empty body on the server... hence i get a 400.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this, `StringEntity requestBody = new StringEntity(<JSON_HERE>, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpPost.setEntity()` accepts [StringEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) which extends [AbstractHttpEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/AbstractHttpEntity.html). you can set it with any valid `String` of your choice:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("www.example.com");
String json = "{\"value\": {\"id\": \"12345\",\"type\": \"weird\"}}";

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
entity.setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType());

request.setEntity(entity);
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

HttpResponse resp = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: For some reason, this returns me a 400, i can get this request to work via postman... :( any other ideas?

Comment: When i check what the server is getting as the body, it gets nothing when i do it this way. However, when i do it the way i posted in my question and add junk values to the BasicNameValuePair, i can see that the server has those values set as the body

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me!

```
HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("www.example.com");
String json = "{\"value\": {\"id\": \"12345\",\"type\": \"weird\"}}";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);

entity.setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType());

request.setEntity(entity);
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that! In case you find my answer helpful for you, feel free to accept the answer :)