# Return String from Apache Http POST Request (Android)

Tags: java, android, json, apache, post

I'm attempting to get a json **string** back from an HTTP post request in my andorid app. Using a solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777929/http-post-with-body), code also shown here.

```
public void post(String completeUrl, String body) {
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(completeUrl);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
try {
    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(body);
    httpPost.getRequestLine();
    httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

    httpClient.execute(httpPost);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

I call post from inside of an Async Task (using to handle network access on a separate thread).

```
String result;
result = post("https://StringURLGoesHere.com/", "jsonStringBodyGoesHere");
```

According to the [documentation for HttpClient class](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler)), to handle the response, I need to add a second parameter ResponseHandler to the HttpClient.execute() method.

```
public interface ResponseHandler<T> {
T handleResponse(HttpResponse var1) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException;
}
```

I did as such:

```
public String post(String completeUrl, String body) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(completeUrl);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        try {
            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(body);
            httpPost.getRequestLine();
            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

            ResponseHandler<String> reply = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
                @Override
                public String handleResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                    return httpResponse.toString();
                }
            };
            return httpClient.execute(httpPost,reply);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I show the string in a textview on my application. It reads:

```
org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@1446ef0c
```

or

```
org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b83bd3d
```

or

```
org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@1c4c9e1d
```

and so on.

Why am I getting this return as a string? What should change in order to get the string of the json object returning after the post?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like below to capture HttpRepose to see your response;
HttpClient request = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();        
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
get.setHeader( "Authorization", token);
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
     response = request.execute( get );
} catch ( ClientProtocolException e ) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( response.getEntity().getContent() ) );

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ( (line = rd.readLine()) != null ) {
      result.append( line );
}

System.out.println( response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() );
System.out.println( result.toString() );
```

Comment: That's quite the elaborate answer, why do you suggest buffered readers in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
    return responseString;  //this is your want
```

Comment: I'm getting a java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream. What might cause this?