# How do I use curl in Java to make a call to a url?

Tags: java, rest, curl, selenium-webdriver, rest-assured

I am using the following CURL command to save the response in .pdf format:

```
curl -d "@name_of_xmlFile.xml" -X POST http:url/ -o name_of_response_pdfFile.pdf
```

how to make the call and save the response generated pdf file in a specific folder using java.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow !

The problem here is that curl is a Linux command. Because Java is intended to be written once and run everywhere (on any machine), then java cannot directly use commands like curl, which do not exist by default on every operating system.

Therefore you need to include additional functionality from elsewhere.

Personally I like to use [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) which is a nice simple lightweight framework to aid with using Rest in Java.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform a post in Java without using curl (not sure whether using curl is a MUST have requirement)

taken from [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) article:

```
private void doPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "http:url/";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    // could ewually save to file rather than to stdout.

}
```

For sending the body, you may try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777929/http-post-with-body).

If using curl is a hard requirement, you may use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` as shown [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/), but be aware that this isn't necessarily portable (e.g. if curl is not installed) and could be unsafe if the commands being run aren't in some way validated to prevent bad actors running arbitrary commands etc...